# get index or tag value from imageview tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

[image]

This is the image from app store whenever we search for any app. I also want to add the same scrollview concept in which it show the currentimage with small preview of previous and next image. I am able to make this view with the help of [Sample code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content). But didn't find any solution that how to get index or tagvalue when user tap any of the image. So that I would be able to open the detail page for each image. If Someone has idea about this please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that it will be better for you to implement this using `UICollectionView` with a cell for every item that scrolls horizontally. Tapping on each cell will lead to a detail screen/view for the item. Here is a tutorial on `UICollectionView`: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 46):

Add gesture recognizer to the necessary image view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *frameTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(frameTapGesture:)];
[_imgView addGestureRecognizer:frameTapGesture];
```

Then in the gesture handler get access to the view gesture recognizer attached to:

```
- (void)frameTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIView *view = sender.view; //cast pointer to the derived class if needed
    NSLog(@"%d", view.tag);
}
```

Comment: I have a question, sorry I'm kind of late. Something weird is happening when I do this. For some reason, it always NSLogs '2' with this code. I have this connected to 4 UIViews, and no matter which one I pressed, It always NSLogs '2'. Help!?!?

Comment: Oh, this is weird. I changed my code from `UIView *view = sender.view;` to `UIView *view = (UIView *)sender.view;`, and now it's only printing '3'. What's going on?!??!

Comment: Thank you. This helped me! :) Should choose this as correct answer.

Comment: Very useful solution

Answer (score 4):

The Best way to achieve what you wish is to add a UITapGesture to your image:

```
let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("openImage:"))
tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
//if you're using a collectionView or tableview add this code inside cellForItemAtIndexPath
cell.Img.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
//otherwise
myImage..addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
```

Get the superview of your tap gesture, this will give you the correct indexPath. Try this:

```
func openImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
{
     let point = sender.view
     let mainCell = point?.superview
     let main = mainCell?.superview
     let cell: myViewCell = main as! myViewCell
     let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
}
```

You can increase or reduce the superview's depending on you hierarchy level. Start from one superview and keep increasing till you get the indexPath

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of making a recommendation without seeing the full picture of your app, why not use a custom UIButton instead of UIImageViews for this? With a UIButton you can setup an action and pass the sender id, from which you can easily access your tags and pull the data from your array.

```
  UIButton *button = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*100 + i*15, 300, 100)];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
button.tag = i;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) controlEvent:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And inside of the touchDown: method you simply have to cast the sender to a UIButton in order to access the tag

```
- (void)touchDown:(id)sender    
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch(button.tag)
    {
        case TAG1:
          break;
        //etc
    }    
}
```

---

OR check this out

```
UIScrollView *myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0,100,200,30)];
NSMutableArray = *images = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: img1,img2,img3,nil];


for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    // set `imageView` frame 
    UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:yourFrame];
    [imageV setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];
    [imageV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:     self action:@selector (getTag:)];
    [imageV addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];
    [myScroll addSubview:imageV];

}
```

set tag to images as per you want 
After adding all imageView successfully you get them click like this :-

```
-(void)getTag:(id)sender
{
     UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
     UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

     if(imageView.image.tag==1)
     {
         [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]];
     }
}
```

Comment: It will not make the view as I needed @Emi_believer

Comment: ok. then tell me in points what do you exactly want. like 1--this, 2-- this

Comment: i have updated the answer check this out .. if it helps you then please mark my answer green , cheers

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array with the objects to display and a `UIImageView` to display the image, just do this when setting up the view with the index `i`:

```
imageView.tag = kImageTag + i;
```

where `kImageTag` is any constant > 1 to make sure you don't get a 0 as the tag.

Now when the view is selected you can simply check for the tag of the image view.

Comment: I can't implement this in given sample. If possible can u check sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue and really thanks to all to look upon my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those using `storyboards` and `swift`:

1. Change tag of every UIView or UIImageView in IB (interface builder) ex:

   ```
   view1.tag = 1
   view2.tag = 2
   view3.tag = 3
   ...
   ```
2. Still in storyboard add UITapGestureRecognizer to every UIView you have put in storyboard view (view1, view2, view3 ...) :

[image: screenshot of UITapGestureRecognizers (9 in picture)]

3. Write your function in Swift file:

// code in swift file :

```
    @IBAction func viewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
            // You can write anything here. I'm guessing you need something with 'enable/disable' function, and the best call is the CustomView which you create from File > New file
            print("tapped view is view with tag: \(sender.view!!.tag)")
        }
```

4. Connect every TapGestureRecognizer to same function you have declared in parent UIViewController swift file:

[image: Established connection between UITapGestureRecognizer and func written in swift file]

5. Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func tapOnRatingInfo(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  guard let index = sender.view?.tag else {
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
@objc func tabAction(_ sender: YourView){
   /*
   Its weird, sender is not type of `YourView` it is `UITabGestureRecognizer`.
   You can get `YourView` reference from gesture
   */
   let tabedView = sender.view as? YourView
}
```