# Find sender's tag with gesture recognizer and swift

Tags: ios, swift, tags, uigesturerecognizer

tl;dr :  **how should I set my tags so that they can be retrieved with the gesture recognizer ?**

I'm setting a view in which the user can spawn multiple UIImageViews when he presses a button. 
The image creation process is :

```
var siegeView: UIView!
var round1: UIImageView!
var setTag : Int!
var tagCounter = 0

 @IBAction func showContent(sender: AnyObject) {


    round1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))

    round1.image = UIImage(named: nomDuRond.text)

    setTag = tagCounter
    tagCounter++
    self.rond1.tag = setTag

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(round1.frame.origin.x+50, round1.frame.origin.y+100)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = nomDuRond.text

    siegeView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(round1.frame.origin.x, round1.frame.origin.y, round1.frame.size.width, round1.frame.size.height))

    round1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    siegeView.addSubview(rond1)
    siegeView.addSubview(label)

    view.addSubview(siegeView)

    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handlePan:"))
    recognizer.delegate = ClassSiege()
    siegeView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

Then the user can move the created images using the Gesture Recognizer's fonction "handlePan" below :

```
 func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(recognizer.view!)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x,
        y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    var centerBoardX = BlackBoard.center.x
    var centerBoardY = BlackBoard.center.y
    var centerRondX = round1.superview?.center.x
    var centerRondY = round1.superview?.center.y
    var switchRang = premierRang

    DistanceCenterY.text = " \(centerRondY! - centerBoardY)"


    if centerRondY! - centerBoardY < 100 {
        switchRang.setOn(true, animated: true)

        println("dans switch if")
    } else {

        switchRang.setOn(false, animated: true)
        println("dans switch else")
    }

}
```

My goal, for now, is to be able to get the DistanceCenterY information, and the if operation to be active for each view the user is moving. But it's only working for the last view created. 
My guess is that it can work if I specify the image's tag. 
But I can't figure out **how to retrieve the tag of the image that is currently being moved by the user**.

I tried this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389683/get-index-or-tag-value-from-imageview-tap-gesture), but it's not the image's tag as it always returns 0 even if the tag is different.

So, my question is : **how should I set my tags so that they can be retrieved with the gesture recognizer ?**

I'm deeply stuck here, so any help would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks

**Update 1 :** 
Thanks to Rdelmar, I've been able to move forward... but not too far !

I updated the way I create the image, and modified the Gesture Recognizer fonction to use the tag info to get the info of which image is selected.

The code is :

var siegeView: UIView!
    var rond1: UIImageView!
    var rond2: UIImageView!
    var setTag : Int!
    var tagCounter = 1
    var tagInfo = 0

```
  func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x,
        y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


    var switchRang = premierRang
    //Here I'm getting the tag from the recognizer. 
    var tag = recognizer.view?.tag
    tagInfo = tag!


    var centerBoardX = BlackBoard.center.x
    var centerBoardY = BlackBoard.center.y
    //to get the coordinates of the image, i'm getting the info using the tag I got earlier. 
    var centerRondX = rond1.viewWithTag(tagInfo)!.center.x
    var centerRondY = rond1.viewWithTag(tagInfo)!.center.y

    DistanceCenterY.text = " \(centerRondY - centerBoardY)"


    if centerRondY - centerBoardY < 100 {
        switchRang.setOn(true, animated: true)

        println("dans switch if")
    } else {

        switchRang.setOn(false, animated: true)
        println("dans switch else")
    }

}
```

and the showcontent fonction updated :

```
@IBAction func showContent(sender: AnyObject) {


    rond1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))

    rond1.image = UIImage(named: nomDuRond.text)

    setTag = tagCounter
    tagCounter++
    rond1.tag = setTag

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(rond1.frame.origin.x+50, rond1.frame.origin.y+100)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = nomDuRond.text

    rond1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(rond1)
    //the label subview was getting me some bugs, so for now I removed it. 
    //view.addSubview(label)

    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handlePan:"))
    recognizer.delegate = ClassSiege()
    rond1.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

**The tag returned is correct when I move the image, but when I adding a second image and I'm moving the first one, I get a fatal error because a nil was returned for the line** `var centerRondY = rond1.viewWithTag(tagInfo)!.center.y`

I'm still stuck because I can't find what's wrong. It's not clear to me how the recognizer is working. If you have some clues, it's still very very much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: The recognizer has a view property, so  you just need to query recognizer.view.tag

Comment: Yes, I tried that but i only get 0 even if the image's tag is different. Do you think that the recognizer.view.tag should refer to the image's tag or should I use a different way to tag my view it's accessible from recognizer.view.tag ?

Comment: You should add the tag to siegeView instead of the image view, since that's the view returned by recognizer.view (or add the label to the image view, and don't use siegeView at all -- it's not clear why you are creating the siegeView).

Comment: Well, thanks because it kinda worked. I removed the uiview, and the taging works pretty much ok... as long as I have only one image. When a second image pop's out, then the apps panic when I'm trying to move the first image. It throws a fatal error because a nil was returned. I'll add an update to my code upthere.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't even need to use a tag, because each image view has it's own gesture recognizer (or it should have anyway), and it's view property will point to the view it's attached to. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do with, rond1.viewWithTag(tagInfo). round1 doesn't  have any subviews does it? You should edit your question to show the whole showContent function as it is now.

Comment: Done ! the main purpose for me is to be able to move individually each image and just by changing their position on the screen giving them various properties. Here, if the image is above 100 pixels on the Y axis, then the UISwitch is true. But without any taging it's not working because only the last image created gets the handlepan's code working. The previous images are still movable, but they do not update their position, nor they change the switch. That's why I was thinking of using a tag system to clearly call the image that is being moved and not the last one created.

Comment: A couple of questions. Where is the label supposed to be? You create it, but it's not added to anything. Should it be a subview of the imageView? Is there just one switch? Is it supposed to change its state whenever the image view you're currently dragging goes to 100 points above the Y axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this code does what you want. I commented some stuff out, since I didn't know what it was, and I hard coded the image and text in the label. As I said in my comment, you don't need to use tags, since each recognizer knows its own view. I commented out the button stuff, but I do see the "if" and "else" log statements fire as I move the views up and down the screen,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showContent(sender: AnyObject) {

        var rond1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        rond1.image = UIImage(named:"Lofoten.jpg")

        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(rond1.frame.origin.x+50, rond1.frame.origin.y+100)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "Picture"
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, rond1.frame.size.height - 25, 100, 25)

        rond1.addSubview(label)
        rond1.userInteractionEnabled = true

        view.addSubview(rond1)
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handlePan:"))
        rond1.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    }

    func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let iv = recognizer.view
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        iv.center.x += translation.x
        iv.center.y += translation.y
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
       // var switchRang = premierRang

        var centerBoardY = self.view.center.y
        var centerRondY = iv.center.y

        //DistanceCenterY.text = " \(centerRondY - centerBoardY)"

        if centerRondY - centerBoardY < 100 {
            //switchRang.setOn(true, animated: true)

            println("dans switch if")
        } else {

            //switchRang.setOn(false, animated: true)
            println("dans switch else")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Looks great. At this point `iv.center.x += translation.x`the compiler complains that "UIView? does not have a member named center". I'm not sure why... Do you have this warning ?

Comment: You did it ! It works ! I just added `let iv : UIView! = recognizer.view`Thanks a lot ! So to be sure that I got it, I was trying to get a tag from the recognizer function, but that was not needed as I can call the own parameters of the recognizer himself like you did ? Right ?

Comment: @NicolasKalogeropoulos, yes that's correct. Each recognizer only knows about its own view, so any translations you make, will only affect that view.

Comment: On a related topic, I was searching for a way to add a custom property to my images generated with the code above. Let's say that I'm passing a "positionUnder100" as a bool when I'm generating the image and when I'm moving it, regarding it's position on the screen the bool changes from true to false... I'm not sure it's even possible to do so, but maybe you know :)

Comment: @NicolasKalogeropoulos, sure that's possible. Subclass UIImage (or UIImageView wherever you want the property), and add a single BOOL property to its .h file.