# Add action to a programmatically created ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, action, user-interaction

I have created image view through code like this -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

  UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
  dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:dot];

}
```

I want to add User Interaction to this `UIImageView` and then create a selector or action for this `UIImageView` when tapped how is this done?

Comment: Use a UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Can you please write a code sample in answer please I do not know how to assign a UITapGestureRecognizer. I am very new to Objective-C

Comment: If you're very new, then you should read the documentation - type "gesture recognizers" into Xcode's documentation search, and that will get you to a document that explains how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of action you want achieve. Generally speaking you'd be using UIGestureRecognizer. For instance if you want your image to respond to a tap gesture then you'd have something like the following.
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
      dotArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

```
  for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++) {
     UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] ...
     dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
     dot.tag = i; //identify dot image.
     [self.view addSubview:dot];
     [dotArray addObject:dot];
     [dot addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
     ...
  }

  [tapGesture release];
}
```

Then the methods to handle tap gesture...

```
-(void)handleTapGesture:(id)sender {
  UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
  for(int i = 0; i<[dotArray count]; i++) {
     UIImageView * dot = (UIImageView*)[dotArray objectAtIndex:i];
     if(dot.tag == [tapGesture view].tag) {
       //fade out animation
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
       dot.alpha = 0.0f;
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

For this to work, you need to make an array of dots and declare it as instance variable, otherwise the method can't access the dot.

Comment: Could you please explain this - when you are in HandleTapGesture and I want to make one of the dots disappear , how to do that? Because I create 30 dots using code so when I tap on one of the dots how to make that dot tapped on disappear?

Comment: I may have to tick you again.

Comment: Did not work sorry. Where did you get dotArray from?

Comment: dotArray would be declared in your .h file as an instance variable/property. You then initialize it like so in your viewDidLoad...
    'code'dotArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++) {
       UIImageVIew * dot = ...
       dot.tag = i;
       ...
    }

Comment: Thank you for all your help but I have a finalised answer if you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
[self.view addSubview:dot];
```

1) To implement the number of touch required is 1 refer this:-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[dot addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

- (void)doubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

}
```

2) To implement the number of touch required is 2 refer this:-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[dot addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];

- (void)twoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this - when you are in HandleTapGesture and I want to make one of the dots disappear , how to do that? Because I create 30 dots using code so when I tap on one of the dots how to make that dot tapped on disappear?

Comment: 1 - Yes I am spawning 30 dots in random positions and when tapped on the dot I want `dot.hidden = YES` but I want only the dot that I tapped on to disappear is this possible? Your answer is more detailed but both answers forgot `dot.UserInteractionEnabled = YES;`     Can you please edit your answer to suit my need, Thank you in advance. You have helped me greatly

Comment: Could you please provide a coded example? Thank you

Comment: Inside your tap gesture method you can implement the same. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389683/get-index-or-tag-value-from-imageview-tap-gesture. But first try without setting the tag value.

Comment: I saw that post and it was greatly helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you that helped me I put everyones answers together and got this as my final code.

```
 //
    //  ViewController.m
    //  InvaderRush
    //
    //  Created by Ajay Venkat on 13/12/2014.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 AJTech. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    {
        NSArray *dotArray;

    }
    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
        dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"invader.jpg"];
        [self.view addSubview:dot];
        dot.tag = 1; //identify dot image.


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapped:)];
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [dot addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
            dot.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       NSMutableArray *images =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: dot,nil];


    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(void)doubleTapped:(id)sender {
        UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

        if(imageView.tag==1) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"space_invader.jpg"]];
        }
    }

    -(void)handleTapGesture:(id)sender {
       }
    @end
```