# Tap on cell and get index

Tags: swift

When i tap on a cell i want to receive the index or other identifier specific to that cell. The code works and goes in the tapped function. But how can i receive a index or something like that?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ShowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    if cell.gestureRecognizers?.count == nil {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
        tap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    return cell
}

func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")  
}
```

Comment: There is a solution to your exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34899415/5815633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it. The `sender` is the tap gesture recognizer. The g.r.'s `view` is the cell. Now you can ask the collection view what the index path of this cell is (`indexPathForCell:`).

[image]

Comment: Is it something like sender.view and than?

Comment: You purposely avoided helping them further when you knew exactly what code to paste. They put in the effort.

Comment: What if the gesture recogniser's view is a subview of the cell? Walking up the view hierarchy in code to find the cell is kind of brittle if you ever re-arrange your layout. While this might be technically correct it's kind of unsatisfying.

Comment: @RobertAtkins I don’t agree.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 - 4.2** - Returns index of tapped cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cellIndex = indexPath[1] // try without [1] returns a list.
print(indexPath[1])
chapterIndexDelegate.didTapChapterSelection(chapterIndex: test)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build on Matts answer

first off we add the tap recognizer

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
cell.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then we use the following function to get the indexPath

```
@objc func tapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    //textField or what ever view you decide to have the tap recogniser on
    if let textField = tapGestureRecognizer.view as? UITextField {

        // get the cell from the textfields superview.superview
        // textField.superView would return the content view within the cell
        if let cell = textField.superview?.superview  as? UITableViewCell{

            // tableview we defined either in storyboard or globally at top of the class

            guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {return}
            print("index path =\(indexPath)")

// then finally if you wanted to pass the indexPath to the main tableView Delegate

                self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

            }
    }
}
```