# I need round and text on UIImage, i already achieved square with text but not able to make it round

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need round and text on the round on UIImage like this Image
[Sample Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9DXQ.png)

Here is my code which i achieved already but with square not in round, i need round around the text.

```
+(UIImage*)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.26 green:0.32 blue:0.59 alpha:1.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.imgview.image = [ViewController drawText:@"iOS" inImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye"] atPoint:CGPointMake(30 , 30)];
    self.imgview.layer.cornerRadius = self.imgview.frame.size.height/2;
    self.imgview.clipsToBounds = YES;

}


+ (UIImage*)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.26 green:0.32 blue:0.59 alpha:1.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

For this you have to add some more logic like below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imgview.image = [ViewController drawText:@"iOS Dev" inImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lion"] bgCircleRect:CGRectMake(15, 15, 100, 100)];
}

+ (UIImage*)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image bgCircleRect:(CGRect) bgCircleRect
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(bgCircleRect.origin.x+10, bgCircleRect.origin.y+35, bgCircleRect.size.width, bgCircleRect.size.height);

    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: bgCircleRect cornerRadius: 50];
    [UIColor.redColor setFill];
    [path fill];

    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I need to draw text with round like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9DXQ.png

Comment: @Prashant Please see my updates, you can do with this.

Comment: Great @Prashant

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for corner radius :

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.26 green:0.32 blue:0.59 alpha:1.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
imageView.center = point;
imageView.image = newImage; }
```

Add image to imageView and add that as subView to your main view

Comment: newImage is UIImage not an UIImageView, UIImage don't have property like layer or frame.

Comment: Oh, do it for your imageView

Comment: this image doesn't explain much what do you want exatly

Answer (score 0):

For making the UIImageView round, First check whether the length and width is same, then apply the following code in the viewDidLoad()

```
yourpic.layer.cornerRadius = yourpic.frame.size.width / 2;
yourpic.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I think this will do.

Comment: You first make the uiimage view round. The label which contains the writing can be put inside the image view and give the appropriate constraints. The code I posted will make the image view rounded

Comment: Ok your need is that you want a rounded text inside your image View is it??

Comment: I don't want imageview as round, please check url which i gave in comment.  Once i Tap on image then at that point i need to make that blue circle with text.

Comment: For that you need to work on with tap gesture and a view. I will try to find out the code. Anyway sorry for the wrong answer

Comment: Just see this link this may help you out. In the gesture handler put a code for making a view appear and diappear (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389683/get-index-or-tag-value-from-imageview-tap-gesture)

Comment: just see this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389683/get-index-or-tag-value-from-imageview-tap-gesture)